# Can't login to SQL Azure Management

Tags: windows, azure

Actually i have following step by step from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/getting-started-w-sql-databases/ to create database and etc.

But when i try to login using username and password which i have configured,message error appear " Failed to retrieve connection information. Try to login again. "

I have configure firewall before to allowed my public ip to access the database.

How to solve my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you still experience this error or has it been gone?

Comment: This issue has not been fixed for me , 
When I press "Manage" Button it doesn't appear any action.

Then I click the link on right side "https://sxsg1wftzf.database.windows.net/?langid=en-us#$database=Toriq_database" . Then I submit my username and password and issue occur.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cookies and browsing history and contact Microsoft support if this persists after some time (like an hour)

Comment: I click the link on right side "https://sxsg1wftzf.database.windows.net/?langid=en-us#$database=Toriq_database" . Then I submit my username and password and issue occur.

Answer (score 0):

That is very interesting problem.

What about checking connection with Microsoft SQL Server (can be [Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx)).

If you configured firewalls then you should be able to access Azure database via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio from your system with no problems.

[image: SQL Management Studio]

Alternatively you could check Visual Studio. But I am not sure if Visual Studio Express edition can connect to Azure databases (you might need some paid version).

If you still have some connectivity issue using SQL Management Studio then that would indicate some networking problems between your place and Azure data centre. In that case I would recommend spinning up another Azure database (for very short time) in different data centre, set up firewalls and see if that will work.

**EDIT**

> Any way to configure Firewall for Azure ?

Firewall to database cannot be configured at a level of individual databases; it needs to be configured at a level of server.

In Windows Azure Management portal, go to Database tab and then select database server:

[image: Windows Azure SQL Dashboard]

Once you in server dashboard, select *configuration* top tab. You can change DB Server firewall allowed IP addresses under *Allowed IP Addresses*

In the same section there is *Current Client IP Address* which tell you the current IP. That very handy when you work with VPN or change your network quite often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Tom , 
Any way to configure Firewall for Azure ?

Answer (score 0):

Allow popups. Chrome was blocking this from me.